# Removed one usercontrol from the main form, now all other usercontrols cant be found in the Designer of the main form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Working with C# (Windows Forms) in Visual Studio 2017

Hello everyone,

in the programm I'm working on, I basically have one main form and a few usercontrols that can be swapped through with buttons. I have all of the user controls existing from the beginning and then the button brings them to the front.

I wanted to remove one of the usercontrols and replace it with an existing one, so I just selected the old usercontrol and hit delete, then tried to drag in the new usercontrol from the toolbox. When I dragged the new usercontrol in, it added an outdated version, so I tried to rebuild the project, but nothing happened.

Then I restarted Visual Studio and got an error message in the designer of my main form, saying that the type "NewProject.Usercontrol1" cannot be found and that I should make sure it exists in the assembly; and in the code of the main form, it says that the variable "usercontrol1" isnt declared or assigned. I get the same error messages for all the other user controls (Usercontrol1 is the name of one of the usercontrols)

All usercontrols have also disappeared from the toolbox.

No idea where to go from here to be honest, Visual Studio doesnt say anything about those errors and googling them in my language I didnt find anything either.

So I guess my question is, how do I fix that error and, if that works, how do I remove user controls without it messing up the rest of the form?

Comment: Using source control and having small reasonable commits and having a branching strategy will be much of help in such situations and you can easily undo/revert changes.

Comment: In the end it's all code. Make sure that you know about `partial class` and `.Designer.cs` files. Then track down the compiler errors one by one. Sounds like you removed 1 or more files.

Comment: Anyway, in this case assuming you don't have any backup/commit history, first you need to backup the current state of the project. Then first of all, try to have a successful build of the solution. To do so, clean and rebuild solution. If your form has some errors which prevent building the solution, you can exclude it from the project then rebuild the solution. So the custom controls will appear in toolbox.

Comment: Then include the form again in the project and if the designer was showing correctly, continue working. If for any reason designer is not showing correctly, you need to open designer.cs file and try to fix the problem yourself.

Comment: And i do agree with Reza, use source Control. If only on your local machine.

Comment: When you "just selected the old usercontrol and hit delete" what exactly did you select? was it in the Form designer or did you select the usercontrol in the solution tree? If the latter, is it possible you mistakenly deleted the class from the project?